# Multiple Add to Cart Button from External php site using product id

Tags: product, addtocart, external

I have tried url method `http://domain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=72&qty=1` for adding magento product to cart from external php website but it looks like this method is not working.

I want to have a add to cart button for around 3 products from a single page using may be product id or sku. How can I accomplish this without having to go to magento product view page. I just want **1 quantity with no custom options**. I also wish there was a way to apply coupon code automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer possible as of magento v1.8 which check to make sure you have a valid form key.

But you could always create a custom module to by pass this see 
[Magento - Add a product to the cart via query string without form_key parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153691/magento-add-a-product-to-the-cart-via-query-string-without-form-key-parameter)